# How can I crop images?

Tags: software-recommendation, photos

Is there an image crop tool available for elementary OS?

I usually use [on-line image crop tool](http://www.picresize.com/) for that purpose, but that need internet connection. So I need image processing/crop tool/software for freya.

How can I *install* and *use* them on elementary OS

Answer (score 7):

Photos (and its companion Photo Viewer) is installed by default and can crop images.

[image: Image showing cropping]

Answer (score 3):

### [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/)

GIMP is a free graphic manipulation tool.

*Installation*:

1. From **software center**.

   [image]
2. You can also install it through the terminal, if you are comfortable doing that, by running this command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gimp
   ```
3. For the latest version, with newer features, use a PPA as [GIMP suggests](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gimp
   ```

---

[image]

Comment: @DanielForé I guess you want answer to be simple like this ^ :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use PImagizer to resize one by one, or use Converseen to resize many images.

You can install it by the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install converseen
```

[image: resize more than one[![][3]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi4Gx.png)

Comment: please provide details like how to install and comment with @Ravan, I will come and give you upvote =)

Comment: @Ravan will this do ^^

Comment: @Tim yeah ^_^ I gave an upvote already :)